# Component's server as another component's client in REST

Tags: http, rest

I read about the key components of a standard REST architecture  at this [page](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/rest-architecture-components.html). It says:

> The system has a client-server, but of course one component's server
>   can be another component's client.

**One**. Can I get a theoretical example of such a case?

**Two**. Can I get a practical example of such a case? I wonder how to do this effectively:

If any resource request is done by URL (and as a result, an HTTP request), and one component's server is the client of another component, I guess we'll have an **internal HTTP request within the same server**.

In this situation, in order to maintain uniformity/consistent interface, we have to do a normal HTTP request by URL - but such action is an overhead when it comes to the same server, isn't it?
Maybe the request package may not leave the server's network? If so, always? I'd love for details.

Comment: It doesn't have to be within the same server - in fact, that's a key advantage - today two services may happen to be on the same machine but could be split out and scaled independently

Comment: server to server is usually on a fast backbone as well.  I've also worked on a system where we had a cloud service and on-prem product and it talked over http in the cloud and in-proc in the shipping on-prem.  Easy to abstract out via an interface

Comment: Imagine the following scenario: You read some post on Facebook. As a client, you (your browser) would like to get the amount of Likes the post has received, from the Likes resource in the server. Further, the Likes resource asking for the id-numbers of the profiles clicked ​​Like (in order to prepare the Like-list) from the Profiles resource. You claim the Likes resource and the Profiles resource shouldn't be on the same server or application?

Comment: Anyway, assuming it should (because it happens a lot and also desirable in small applications), how was the communication between the resources is done? Outbound HTTP request?